# react-dom.development.js:16317 Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

```
let [depart, setdepartment] = useState({
        Frontend: 0,
        Backend: 0,
        Testing: 0,
        Deployment: 0,
    });
    Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function (key, value) {
        let temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
        setdepartment(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            [temp.department]: depart.Frontend.value +1,
        }));
    });
```

I want if the localStorage data object has department of frontend,backend,testing,deployment then its value will increase by 1.

```
let [depart, setdepartment] = useState({
        Frontend: 3,
        Backend: 1,
        Testing: 1,
        Deployment: 2,
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the state when you loop over the localstorage. This will update the state causing a re-render and the re-render will loop over the localstorage again.

To prevent this you could use a `useEffect`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function (key, value) {
    let temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    setdepartment(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      [temp.department]: depart.Frontend.value +1,
    }));
  });
}, []);
```